# The meaning of commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, jordan-normal-form

I have a question when I study the Lie algebra.

The following sentence is written in the book related to Lie algebra, but the contents is just a linear algebra:

Since $diag(a,\cdots,a)$ commutes with the nilpotent matrix having one's just above the diagonal and zeros elsewhere, $x$ is the sum of a diagonal and a nilpotent matrix which commute. We can make this decomposition more precise, as follows.

This book is "Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation theory, James E. Humphreys, Second printing, revised", and the page is 17.

I cannot understand why the contition "commute" is the crucial reason for the expression of the sum of a diagonal and a nilpotent matrix. What is the connection between them? I'm wating your best answer. Thanks.

Best.

Comment: I don't think they are saying that the commutativity implies that it can be written as the sum of the diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix, I think the commutativity is mentioned to emphasize that the diagonal and nilpotent matrix in the decomposition happen to commute. Hopefully the reason that the matrix can be decomposed into a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix is specified earlier (and is far too complicated for me to explain in the scope of this comment).

Comment: @Christian Thank you. I've already studied about Jordan canonical form in the linear algebra lecture. But in this lecture, I cannot recognize the relation between the commutativity and the decomposition. In fact, I don't know why the commutativity is emphasized in this point. "Since" is used to describe the direct reason, right? So, I think I have to check why it is, but I can't.

Comment: I think the only relationship between the commutativity and the decomposition is when we have $A = D + N$, we also have $DN = ND$. To me it seems like bad phrasing; you're right, using "since" makes it seem like commutativity is the reason for all that follows, which I  think is not what the author intended. I think "We can write $A = N + D$ because of (all Jordan Canonical form reasons), and since $D$ and $N$ commute, the decomposition is into commutative matrices" was intended. I don't know much about Lie Algebras; perhaps this $DN = ND$ is important later and he wants to emphasize it now?

Comment: But to my knowledge, the commutativity of the matrices has no bearing on the fact that there exists such a decomposition.

Comment: @Christian Yeah, moreover I think the author may abuse of notation because the sum of a diagonal and a nilpotent matrix which commute is not $x$, but a block of $x$. Anyway, I'll study this point together with your advice. Thank you! Have a nice day. :)

Comment: This might come up in the context of computing the exponential of a matrix. In that context, the matrices $A$ and $B$ must commute for the identity $\exp(A+B)=\exp(A)\exp(B)$ to hold. The exponentials of a diagonal and nilpotent matrix are particularly easy to compute, so being able to decompose a matrix into the sum of such matrices is an important tool.

Comment: @amd Oh, it's a simple but very powerful observation! Thank you:)